# I have a problem about the paginator helper in Cakephp

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-1.3

I follow in example in book.cakephp and I try to search solution for it but not found
this it problem

```
Warning (512): Method PaginatorHelper::option does not exist    [CORE\cake\libs\view\helper.php, line 154]
Code | Context
Helper::call__() - CORE\cake\libs\view\helper.php, line 154
Overloadable::__call() - CORE\cake\libs\overloadable_php5.php, line 50
PaginatorHelper::option() - APP\views\layouts\default.ctp, line 41
include - APP\views\layouts\default.ctp, line 41
View::_render() - CORE\cake\libs\view\view.php, line 731
View::renderLayout() - CORE\cake\libs\view\view.php, line 489
View::render() - CORE\cake\libs\view\view.php, line 435
Controller::render() - CORE\cake\libs\controller\controller.php, line 909
Dispatcher::_invoke() - CORE\cake\dispatcher.php, line 207
Dispatcher::dispatch() - CORE\cake\dispatcher.php, line 171
[main] - APP\webroot\index.php, line 83
```

minimize code User Controller and view
[enter link description here](http://bin.cakephp.org/view/272464420)

Thank for answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be ([api](http://api.cakephp.org/class/paginator-helper#method-PaginatorHelperoptions))

```
$this->Paginator->options(...
```

instead of

```
$this->Paginator->option(...
```

(note the **s**)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: hey next But it's doesn't work 
can you tell solution to debug ajax in cake,pls

Comment: you have to set up both clientside and serverside debuggers.
on the serverside i've used xdebug (with eclipse) and on the clientside: firebug (in firefox) or google chrome's inspector

then you add breakpoints and start debugging

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the AjaxHelper included in your code.